# Web config transform for custom section

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, web.config-transform, web-config-transform

I have numerous different Web.configs in my MVC 5 Application for different environments - e.g. Test/Prod

I have web transforms in place to change values for the different environments.  So for example I have the following app setting in my web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="DevDisplayPanel" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Then in my Web.Test.config and Web.Prod.config using a web transform to change the value as below:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="DevDisplayPanel" 
     xdt:Transform="Replace" 
     xdt:Locator="Match(key)" 
     value="false" />
<appSettings>
```

However in my Web.config I also have my own custom section which is outside the `<appSettings>` section and is as below:

```
  <myCustomSection>
    <serverList>
      <add zone="Zone1" url="https://dev-myurl1.com"/>
      <add zone="Zone2" url="https://dev-myurl2.com"/>
      <add zone="Zone2" url="https://dev-myurl3.com"/>
    </serverList>
  </myCustomSection>
```

My question is - is it possible to have a web transform so that for Test and Prod would look as below:

Test:

```
  <myCustomSection>
    <serverList>
      <add zone="Zone1" url="https://test-myurl1.com"/>
      <add zone="Zone2" url="https://test-myurl2.com"/>
      <add zone="Zone2" url="https://test-myurl3.com"/>
    </serverList>
  </myCustomSection>
```

Prod:

```
  <myCustomSection>
    <serverList>
      <add zone="Zone1" url="https://prod-myurl1.com"/>
      <add zone="Zone2" url="https://prod-myurl2.com"/>
      <add zone="Zone2" url="https://prod-myurl3.com"/>
    </serverList>
  </myCustomSection>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try replacing the contents of the `<serverList>` tag.

Test:

```
<myCustomSection>
    <serverList xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <add zone="Zone1" url="https://test-myurl1.com"/>
        <add zone="Zone2" url="https://test-myurl2.com"/>
        <add zone="Zone2" url="https://test-myurl3.com"/>
    </serverList>
</myCustomSection>
```

Prod:

```
<myCustomSection>
    <serverList xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <add zone="Zone1" url="https://prod-myurl1.com"/>
        <add zone="Zone2" url="https://prod-myurl2.com"/>
        <add zone="Zone2" url="https://prod-myurl3.com"/>
    </serverList>
</myCustomSection>
```

Comment: I had this problem, but I had simply misspelled a tag in one case and used the wrong case in another.   Using SlowCheetah [https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5]