# How to configure web.config transform for custom configuration elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, web.config-transform

I have a custom element inside web.config file for which I am trying to write xdt so that I can get different values for each of my configuration modes.

I have a custom element like below:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <containers>
      <container name="Service">
        <register type="" mapTo="" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(type)" xdt:Locator="Match(mapTo)" />
        <register type="" mapTo="" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(type)" xdt:Locator="Match(mapTo)" />
      </container>
    </containers>
  </unity>
```

I have also added xdt element as well. But after publish the expected value is not getting generated.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917289/web-config-transform-for-custom-section)? Personally, I prefer [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-inline-tasks?view=vs-2019#example) because I can transform at debug time instead of just publish time.

Comment: Thanks for the link